# I want to make test cases for request module call in Sinon (TDD) but when i made stubs for that it stopped on request call part

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, request, mocha.js, sinon

This code contains a login function in which it takes a encrypted key as a parameter and and after that it decrypted it and then make a request call using request node module. I want to make a test cases for that.

```
var request = require('request');
var Check = require('../libs/core/Check');
var util = require('./../libs/core/utility');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var decrypted_key;
var vendor = {};
vendor.login = function (encrypted, callback) {
  util.decryption(encrypted, function (err, decrypted) {
    decrypted_key = decrypted;
  });
  /*input data for request call*/
  var requestVar = {
    url: 'some URL',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + decrypted_key,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };
  //request call 
  request(requestVar, function (err, data) {
    if (err)
      callback(err, null);
    else {
      if (data == undefined || data == "") {
        var temp = JSON.stringify({ status_code: 401 });
        temp = JSON.parse(temp);
        callback(null, temp);
      }
      else {
        data = JSON.stringify({ auth_key: decrypted_key });
        callback(null, data);
      }
    }
  });
};
module.exports = vendor;
```